# how to stream h265 video from ffmpeg to amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, libx265

I am trying to stream h265 video to aws s3 from ffmpeg, here is the command that i use:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i desktop -r 1 -vframes 5 -c:v libx265 -crf 40 -f mp4 pipe:1 | aws s3 cp -  s3://videosbuket-009212/d5.mp4
```

and error information:

```
[mp4 @ 000001c49541bb40] muxer does not support non seekable output
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

what's wrong here?

Comment: i wonder if it is possible to stream h265 at all...

Comment: btw, `-f hevc` completes without error, but generated video file cannot play in vlc and other players.

Comment: also tried `-f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov`, it completes without error, but uploaded video can't play neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What’s wrong is that mp4 does not support non seekable output. Just like the error reads. Use a format that doesn’t not requires seeking, like mkv. If you require mp4, then you must make a local copy first.

Comment: `[NULL @ 000002a8d8f1c200] Requested output format 'mkv' is not a suitable output format
pipe:1: Invalid argument`, i finally make -f hevc work by upgrading to latest vlc...